# Old topographic maps of Odisha, India

Tags: mapping, topography, cartography

For my research related to coastal Odisha, India I am mapping the coastal boundary. I have downloaded available Landsat images which date back to 1972. But I want to map the same for before 1972.

I am interested in old topographic maps showing the coastal boundary of Odisha, preferably before 1970.

**Does anyone know from where can I get the scanned map of the same?**

Comment: Try [Survey of India Maps](https://indiamaps.gov.in/soiapp/). [Download maps of India provided by Survey of India](https://www.india.gov.in/download-maps-india-provided-survey-india). It may have an archive of older maps.

Comment: The Imperial Gazetteer of India had some maps from around 1907, but I think the ones I could find on line are too small for your purposes https://dsal.uchicago.edu/maps/gazetteer/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [PCL Map Collection](https://maps.lib.utexas.edu/maps/index.html) (University of Texas at Austin) is a huge online collection of maps. For India, they have [a series from the U.S. Army Map Service](https://maps.lib.utexas.edu/maps/ams/india/) which might be of interest, as it dates from the 50's and has a decent scale (1:250,000). They also have older maps from the British era, but the series doesn't seem to be complete. It might be worth looking for those at the Royal Geographical Society archives.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a map of 1961 in PCL Map Collection.